# Divarea plugin not working for ckeditor 3.7.2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ckeditor

I have gone through [ckeditor - div based editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031840/ckeditor-div-based-editor) but it not working for rails 3.2.

I have tried with higher ckeditor gem versions 4.0.0 to 4.0.1 but editor not supporting.

Currently rails 3.2 and ckeditor gem 3.7.2 and ckeditor version 3.6.3.

Can any one tell me how to integrate this plugin with ckeditor?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Div based editor" is a feature of CKEditor 4. 
You can't use it with CKEditor 3.x