# how to write ckeditor code in laravel form view in laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello everyone i want to add ckeditor in my view which has multiple divs. How can i do that by adding this ckeditor code:

```
    <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
  <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
        </textarea>
        <script>
            // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
            // instance, using default configuration.
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

And this is my view

```
@extends('sadmin.main-template')
@section('title', 'Super admin Dashboard')

@section('title', 'Add Plan')


@section('content')
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 right-sidebar admin-client add-client">
    @include('partials.errors')
    <form action="{{url('sadmin/add_plan')}}" class="toggle-disabled" method="post">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <h3 class="title">Add a plan</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label >You Can Create Your Plan Here</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left-client-title">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label name">
                        <span class="form-name">Name</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"  placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label name">
                        <span class="form-name">Price</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="price"  placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right-client-title">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label name">
                        <span class="form-name">Allowed Users</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="allowed_users"  placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label name">
                        <span class="form-name">Can Trail</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="canTrail" name="can_trail"  placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
                    </label>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label name">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left-client-title">
                        <span class="form-name">Trail Duration</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="trail_duration"  placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
                    </label>

                        <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label name">
                        <span class="form-name">Detail 1</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="passwordConfirmation" name="detail1"  placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation="required">
                    </label>
                </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right-client-title">
                    <label class="form-label name">
                        <span class="form-name">Detail 2</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="detail2" placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
                    </label>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label name">
                        <span class="form-name">Staff Profiles</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="planName" name="staff_profiles" placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
                    </label>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left-client-title">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label name">
                        <span class="form-name">Space Management</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="planPrice" name="space_management" placeholder="" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$">
                    </label>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right-client-title">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label name">
                        <span class="form-name">Currency Unit</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="allowedUsers" name="currency_unit" placeholder=""data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$" >
                    </label>
                </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right-client-title">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label name">
                                <span class="form-name">Location charges</span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="allowedUsers" name="location_charges" placeholder=""data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^([A-Za-z ]+)$" >
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>



        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                <div align="center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="padding-left:90px; padding-right:90px;"><strong>Submit</strong></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</section>


</div>

@endsection
```

How i can apply ckeditor code in each div any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15323559/3282633) helps you ?

Comment: No it does not helps me cant find a way how i can do it in multiple divs